# Reading a contacts in my android device using appium by scrolling till end of all contacts list

Tags: appium

I am facing a issue in reading contacts list my android device using appium.
My goal is to read all the contacts in android device by scrolling till end of page and Exit after reaching end of the last contact.

I used the following piece of code.

```
package sampleinfo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;

public class Readingcontacts extends sampleappiumlaunch{

    List<String>previous=new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String>current=new ArrayList<String>();

        public void scrolltillEnd(){

            System.out.println("Intiated method to read contacts of current window");
              readContacts();

              while(!current.equals(previous)){

                  System.out.println("Intiated method to Scroll...");
                  verticalScroll();

                     System.out.println("adding current window contacts to previous window list");
                     previous.addAll(current);

                     System.out.println("@@@@@@Previous List is of elements were....@@@@"+previous);

                     System.out.println("Intiated method to read contacts of current window");
                     readContacts();

              }

                 System.out.println("****End of while loop..reached end of page..***");
                 String finalcontact = current.get(current.size() - 1);
                 System.out.println("Final contact name is"+finalcontact);

        }

        public void readContacts(){
            String layout = "android.widget.ListView";
            MobileElement Rootelframe = (MobileElement) appiumdriver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator(
                    "new UiSelector().className(\"" + layout + "\").enabled(true).instance(0)");

            List<MobileElement>viewgroup=Rootelframe.findElementsByClassName("android.view.ViewGroup");
            for (int i=0;i<viewgroup.size();i++) {

                  try{
                      System.out.println("####..currently in view group index of...####"+i);
                      String str=viewgroup.get(i).findElementByClassName("android.widget.TextView").getText().toString();
                      System.out.println("@@@@@...Current List element is....@@@@"+str);
                      current.add(i, str);
                       }

                catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("currently Text view element is not visiable in view group index of"+i);
                }

            }
            System.out.println("*****current List of elements were.....******"+current);


        }



        public void verticalScroll() {          
            Dimension size=appiumdriver.manage().window().getSize();

      int y_start=(int)(size.height*0.70);
      int y_end=(int)(size.height*0.30);
      int x=size.width/2;

      if(!current.equals(previous)){
        appiumdriver.swipe(x,y_start,x,y_end,5000);
      }
      else{
        System.out.println("Reached end of page");
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am able to scroll till end of page, but unable to come out of while loop even after reaching end of the page.

Answer (score 0):

The condition that you put is not valid. The variables **current** and **previous** will never match. You can try below code by setting the flag in the else part of **verticalScroll()** method and checking the same flag in the while loop.

**Declare boolean variable class called isPageEndReached=false. And set the value to true if it reaches the page end. And check the value in the loop if its' true then break the loop.**

Answer (score 0):

Clear Previous and Current before populating them and instead of `current.add(i, str);` use `current.add(str);`